How to resolve the 500 Internal server error in app while recording the scripts in JMeter?
Setup (JMeter configuration & proxy in JMeter & browser) has been done.
Started recording the scripts in JMeter.
At exactly downloading functionality, getting an internal server error in application.
Note:

Checked out of JMeter, it's downloading successfully.
Explored an extension (Blazemeter), Checked. Here, missing some actions to record ie., my app is not responding correctly.

I have tried some extensions, checked in app out of JMeter, checked the JMeter configuration.
getting an internal server in app using JMeter


First of all I would check jmeter.log file for any suspicious entries, it might be the case either JMeter or your browser configuration (or both) is not correct.
If you're a "QA" you should be able to inspect requests using your browser developer tools and come up with manual configuration of HTTP Request sampler, HTTP Header Manager, etc.
However if it doesn't suit your needs, i.e. due to large number of requests and you need to deliver the script fast you can export the requests from the aforementioned browser developer tools into a .HAR file and then use either har-convertor-jmeter-plugin or BlazeMeter Converter to build your .jmx script from the HAR file.
Also pay attention to this post, it's regarding your "ASAP" bit.
